# Is it possible, that each node can only call an extrinsic function once?

Tags: substrate

Hi im working on a project and i would like the functionallity, of a function that can only be called once for each node, is this possible? Or is it possible to get the peer id?

Comment: So if my network is composed of 4 nodes, you should only be able to call, for example, transfer function 4 times?

Comment: exactly .......

Comment: You could do something like this for the number of validators on your network. Assuming that you have some author rotation logic (like Babe or Aura), you can make an extrinsic so that it can only be called once per block. For example, you store some bool after the call which checks if it has been called. Then, as blocks are produced, each validator will process that extrinsic up to one time per block. But in general, your idea is not clear and not really normal for a blockchain system.